# How to list Azure Batch Pools from PowerShell using the account key?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-batch

Using the [Azure Batch PowerShell cmdlets](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/batch-powershell-cmdlets-get-started/), I would like to list the pools within an existing Azure Batch account using the *Azure Batch account primary key*.

The documentation hints how to do that with full login to the Azure subscription, however, I am specially interested in restricting the access to only what the Azure Batch account key offer, instead of granting an access to the whole subscription.

Phased differently, I am trying to achieve for Azure Batch what `New-AzureStorageContext` does for the Azure Storage when passing `-StorageAccountKey` as argument.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to that?

Comment: No, I did not :(

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-AzBatchPool -BatchContext $context
```

this will list all pools. there are query filters in [this.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-powershell-cmdlets-get-started)